# APIs and JavaScript entry mappings clarification

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, axios

I have a test app which queries 2 different APIs

The first checks NPM downloads (and returns a response as shown):

```
//FIRST API CALL
{"start":"2017-01-01",
 "end":"2017-01-02",
 "package":"vue",
 "downloads":[{"downloads":2677,"day":"2017-01-01"},
              {"downloads":5329,"day":"2017-01-02"},]}
```

My tutorial code maps the entries like so:

```
axios.get(`https://api.npmjs.org/downloads/range/2017-01-01:2017-01-02/vue`)
          .then(response => {
            this.rawData2 = response.data.downloads
            this.labels = response.data.downloads.map(entry => entry.day)
            this.downloads2 = response.data.downloads.map(entry => entry.downloads)
```

The second queries a MongoDB (and returns a response as shown):

```
[{"_id":"5e7b4708cab3f23c0260dc20","test":"123"}]
```

I am trying to adapt the tutorial code to be able to map the mongoDB call. However my confusion lies with the naming conventions used. Looking at the NPM response again `"downloads":[{"downloads":2677,..` - When my tutorial code references 'downloads' e.g, `response.data.downloads`. Is it referring to the initial "downloads" of the response or the specific 'downloads' prefixing the actual downloaded value in the response? I have tried changing "downloads" to "test" to match the response entry. However, no luck.

Similarly the syntax `entry => entry.day` is not clear. While I understand it is going to map the 'day' string to the 'labels' array. I have not been able to find a good explanation of the '=>' for the entries functionality.

Comment: The `=>` is an arrow function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. `response.data.downloads` refers to the 'outer' `downloads` property. `entry.downloads` refers to the 'inner' `downloads` property that is present on each object within the array. Not sure what you're trying to do, but maybe `this.tests = response.data.map(entry => entry.test)`.

Comment: @skirtle That fixed it (had to add CORS to the API). I'm happy to accept that as an answer if you wish to add it.